# Is it OK to not read eventfd to clear the value?

Tags: epoll, event-driven

I use `eventfd` just to wake up `epoll_wait()`. I do not care about the value in `eventfd`. So can I not call `read()` on `eventfd` to avoid one syscall?

My program is restarted every month, so the 64-bit value in eventfd will not overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, yes, you would read() the event FD to "clear" the event. If you don't, then the descriptor remains readable.

However, your specific logic ***may*** not require it, perhaps you can provide more information ?

Maybe you used EPOLLONESHOT, or maybe you explicitly close() the event FD when you get EPOLLIN and stop your program. If that is the case, you can avoid the read syscall.

In general, an event FD that is being monitored by epoll_wait() will continue to generate EPOLLIN until the 64-bit counter in the event FD is zero.

Please see the section `poll(2), select(2) (and similar)` at the link below:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html